# LED on Xperia Z only in operation while charging

Tags: notification-led, sony-xperia-z

Using the LED to know when a notification is available is of great use to me, but my new Sony Xperia Z appears to only turn on the LED notification light while it is on charge.

It turns orange to say it's charging, and turns blue (slow flashing) if I got a missed call or text message, but it will only do so while it's pluggin in. And to confirm I can get a missed call, wait for the LED to turn on, it wont, I put it on charge without disturbing it's 'locked state', and immediately I get slow flashing blue instead of 'charging orange', that is too say I can see before I put it on charge it should be on, but only turns on once i plug it in.

I like how it works while it's charging, but I'd like similar functionality while it isn't charging. I am using STAMINA mode, is this a battry save issue? How can I get the LED working as I'd like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known bug in Xperia Z (sources [1](http://www.xperiablog.net/2013/03/06/xperia-z-suffering-led-notification-issue/) and [2](http://talk.sonymobile.com/thread/120139)).

Currently the only way to restore the LED functionality is to:

- de-select `Settings -> Backup & reset -> Backup my data` and `Automatic restore`
- perform a factory reset from `Settings -> Backup & reset -> Factory data reset`
- Complete the reset manually (that is, without restoring apps/data from the Google account)

Hopefully this will be corrected in the next update.

Comment: that is a scary fix that doesn't intuitively suggest why these steps are needed... can you elaborate? I like my google account data (contacts etc), don't want no data but have a working LED instead. If you can elaborate I'll definitely mark yours as the answer..

Comment: You can keep your Google account data (like contacts, calendar markings etc), but not the backup data (including which apps are installed, WiFi passwords etc). I have no exact explanation for this behaviour, but it seems from the second source link that Xperia Z is not the first Sony device to have similar trouble.

Answer (score 1):

Hi you can use LightFlow to setup how the led should act and in Stamina mode remember to add LightFlow umder apps active in standby mode.

Settings/Powermanagement/Stamina mode/+ add application

You have many possibilities with LightFlow.

Free version
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.rageconsulting.android.lightflowlite

Full version
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.rageconsulting.android.lightflow

Hope this is will help you.

Comment: sorry friend, but this app DID NOT fix the issue, LED did not work if not on charge, I added the app to the Stamina mode. Would have liked to be able to test more thoroughly, but only had 15 minutes after purchase to get a refund, and I needed it, issue still continures